# Google Places Web Service doesn't return any value

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm testing my Android application against Google Places **Web Service API** and I can observe that if I select a **radius between 1000 and 5000 meters**,

for example, I've got results about **restaurants, hotels, supermarkets, gas station, etc**. But, if I select a radius grater than **5000 meters** then the same consult doesn't return any value neither the values that you can get with a **radius between 1000 and 5000 meters**.

Is there any limit to the radius? Anybody knows what happens with **radius** greater than **5000 meters**?

When I make a consult to the Google Places Web Service API with a radius greater than 5000 meters I've got the next response:

```
{
 "html_attributions" : [],
 "results" : [],
 "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug.  Star [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7901) and hopefully they'll fix it soon.